# XNA's SetData in a SharpDX Texture2D object in DirectX 11?

Tags: xna, sharpdx

I'm trying to load a texture given a swap chain, and then populate that texture with data. I already have some bitmap data (although not sure if it is in the correct format) that I want to populate the texture with.

However, XNA's `SetData` method of the `Texture2D` object is obviously not present in SharpDX. What do I do to populate my texture with data? I load the texture using the following code.

```
var texture = Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Device.[UpdateSubresource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (requires texture to be declared with Usage.Default) or [Map/UnMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (requires texture to be declared Usage.Dynamic).In the case of the swapchain, I guess that only UpdateSubresource will work.

Keep in mind that you are refering to the low level Direct3D11 API in SharpDX, so there can't be any high level methods like "SetData". If you want to have XNA equivalent API, you have to use the Toolkit which is available from the 2.5 dev package. If you want to stick with plain Direct3D11, you will have to dig into all the details about how Direct3D11 is working.